# Delay while moving CALayer with pan gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, calayer

I use pan gesture to move an image in CALayer. The issue I experience is that the image appears to move with a little delay and does not appear 'stuck' to my finger.

Here is the actual snippet of how I move the layer(facePic is the CALayer):

```
CGPoint translation =[touche locationInView:self.view];
self.facePic.frame =
CGRectMake(translation.x - self.facePic.frame.size.width/2,
           translation.y - self.facePic.frame.size.height/2,
           self.facePic.frame.size.width,
           self.facePic.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Can you find an example of dragging in another app where there isn't a small delay? There's usually some delay.

Comment: @occulus are you sure there is no way to make it better? I also tried to subclass UIView and move the layer by overriding the touchesMoved method but that had the very same effect which is a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you see the result of *implicit* animation of a layer. If so then there are two options to disable this animation:

1. use transactions
2. set layer actions

To use transactions wrap your code with CATransaction

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
 . . .
[CATransaction commit];
```

To disable some layer actions you can add this to the layer init, the position animation for example:

```
aLayer.actions = @{@"position":[NSNull null]}; // FIXED property name
```

Comment: I think you mean “implicit animation”.  Also, it's shorter to say `[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]`.

Comment: Also, it should be `aLayer.actions = ...`.  The property name is `actions`, not `action`.